# CodeIgniter translate PHP date

Tags: codeigniter

I have a `datetime` stored in mysql as timestamp.

I then format the datetime using

```
$newdate = date('d M Y', strtotime($this->query->datetime));
```

My question is how do I translate the date using codeigniter builtin lang helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the application language folder add a subfolder for the language you want to translate to. In that folder make a file called date_lang.php and handle all you date translations.

```
 $lang['datefrom'] = "dateTo";
```

Another option for translation of dates is to use locale.

PHP will handle the date translations for you. Set the locale globally for the user.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_UK.utf8');
```

In my current project, we use the locale to handle money and dates. We use CI language files to handle string translations

Comment: My original intention is not depends on setlocale, but anyhow will use setlocale.